# inheritance view and update it

Tags: odoo

i have a question with inheritance view, i've just got what is inheritance view for the function. But i have next question, why must default view, such as: res.partner, must have more than one inheritance view, such as : res.partner.emails.info.inherit

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xpath expr="//field[@name='active']" position="after">
                    <field name="opt_out"/>
                </xpath>
```

and res.partner.opt_out.form

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xpath expr="//sheet" position="after">
                    <div class="oe_chatter">
                        <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                        <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread" options="{"thread_level": 1}"/>
                    </div>
                </xpath>
```

, and many more. why must separated into different file? why just no united it? and then, when i finished making new inheritance view in xml, how to update it? so that it can be inserted to database and directly applied in parent view..

really need your help guys.. thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ERP software is made up of many modules. Each ERP module mimics a major functional area of an organization. Common ERP modules include modules for product planning, parts and material purchasing, inventory control, product distribution, order tracking, finance, accounting, marketing, and HR. Organizations often selectively implement the ERP modules that are both economically and technically feasible and easier to control within the organization’s operating environment.

The default view  of res.partner is actual view of object. Each object have its own default view. Like in sale module partner is supplier or customer then you need to add information in partner so you inherit partner in sale module give its name like 'res.partner.sale_type.info.inherit' and add filed supplier or customer. 
When you directly enticed all changes in single file code and view its make code ugly and too complex

When you add this fields it directly add in partner default view. When you add field then you have to update module so its inserted in database.

You can update your module after change like -u 'your module name' -d 'database name'

or directly go to Settings => Installed Modules => open your module and update it

Hope this help